# Gaussian Mixture model -- how to deal with missing value from the dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, model, gaussian

I'm training a GMM, but I found there's a problem because my dataset includes Nan value.
First, I thought it would be okay if I changed all the NAN to 0. However, when I plot it, we can see this. (The purple line is 0 value)
[image]

Here's a toy dataset and codes that you can try:)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = {'butter': [2, 3, 1, NaN],
        'peanut': [20, 3, Nan, NaN],
         'cheese': [4, 3, 2, 3]
}
 
# Create DataFrame
d = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Here is the model codes

```py
from sklearn import mixture
gmm = mixture.GaussianMixture(n_components=3).fit(d)
labels = gmm.predict(d)
plt.scatter(d.iloc[:, 0], d.iloc[:, 1], c=labels, s=40, cmap='viridis')
```

So how to avoid plotting the NaN or 0 value?
By the way, is it the right way to do GMM (I am not sure)? Does n_components means how many columns I have?

I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

There are more meaningful ways to impute missing values than filling them with 0s. Based on the nature of the problem you need to choose the right one.  [Here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/impute.html) are some.

For example, it could be like this:

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
data = {'butter': [2, 3, 1, np.nan],
        'peanut': [20, 3, np.nan, np.nan],
         'cheese': [4, 3, 2, 3]
}
data = pd.DataFrame(data)
imp_mean = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
imp_mean.fit(data.to_numpy())

print(imp_mean.transform(data.values))
```

output:

```
[[ 2.  20.   4. ]
 [ 3.   3.   3. ]
 [ 1.  11.5  2. ]
 [ 2.  11.5  3. ]]
```

Comment: Thanks for replying!
Yah, Inputting mean instead of NaN is better!
So it's hard to avoid plotting that line(horizontal one with mean value), right?

Comment: I guess with the help of an appropriate imputer the line would disappear.

Comment: I think so too. But after I change those Nan values to mean values, it shows a straight line with several dots on 0.1 or so.

Comment: Would you please add the dataset or even a portion of it?

Comment: Did the answer provide you with any help?